# Multiplying two columns in SQLite and display it in Android studio textview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database

I've been learning how to use SQL in Android studio by learning online templates and tutorial, but none of the tutorials show how to multiply two columns and add the calculated data into a new column.

The task is to multiply cost and quantity to get total.
For now, I've manage to get the basics such as add, update and remove data in SQLite.

Heres my updated current **DBHelper.java**

```
    package ntws.itemsqlite;

/**
 * Created by eddie on 13/4/2017.
 */

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ProductList.db";
    public static final String PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME = "product";
    public static final String PRODUCTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String PRODUCTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String PRODUCTS_COLUMN_COST = "cost";
    public static final String PRODUCTS_COLUMN_QUANTITY = "quantity";
    public static final String PRODUCTS_COLUMN_TOTAL = "total";

    private HashMap hp;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table products " +
                        "(id integer primary key, name text,cost double, quantity double, total double)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products");
        onCreate(db);
    }
public int getAllTotal(int cost){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(cost) FROM products", null);
    if(res.moveToFirst())
    {
        return res.getInt(0);
    }

    return cost;
}

    public boolean insertProduct (String name,  String cost, String quantity) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);

        contentValues.put("cost", cost);
        contentValues.put("quantity", quantity);

        db.insert("products", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from products where id="+id+" ", null );

        return res;
    }

    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }

    public boolean updateProduct (Integer id, String name,  String cost, String quantity) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);

        contentValues.put("cost", cost);
        contentValues.put("quantity", quantity);



        db.update("products", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteProduct (Integer id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("products",
                "id = ? ",
                new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllProduct() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from products", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(PRODUCTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

    public double getItemTotal(int value)
    {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM product";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery(countQuery , null );

        double itemtotal = 0;
        if(res.moveToFirst()){
            String costStr = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("cost"));
            String qntStr = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("quantity"));

            itemtotal = Double.parseDouble(costStr) * Double.parseDouble(qntStr);
            res.close();
        }
        return itemtotal;
    }

    //end of DBHelper

}
```

As you can see, I've tried added in the method call getItemTotal in my DBHelper.java. 
Currently, all other functions are working and I am able to replace the respective datas to the TextViews in the activity_display_product.xml by passing through the DisplayProduct.java

Now is the issue of implementing getItemTotal() into DisplayProduct.Java so that the method function can run the calculation and then update respectively.

*DisplayProduct.Java*

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_product);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

    cost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextCost);
    quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);



    mydb = new DBHelper(this);



    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");

        if(Value>0){
            //means this is the view part not the add PRODUCT part.
            Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
            id_To_Update = Value;
            rs.moveToFirst();

            String nam = 
rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_NAME));

            String cos = 
rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_COST));
            String quantit = 
rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_QUANTITY));


            if (!rs.isClosed())  {
                rs.close();
            }
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            name.setText((CharSequence)nam);
            name.setFocusable(false);
            name.setClickable(false);


            cost.setText((CharSequence)cos);
            cost.setFocusable(false);
            cost.setClickable(false);

            quantity.setText((CharSequence)quantit);
            quantity.setFocusable(false);
            quantity.setClickable(false);


        }
    }
```

The total value should replace the TextView in the activity_display_product.xml

**update**

I know i should add the getItemTotal method from the DBHelper to the onCreate of DisplayProduct.java but I have no idea how to implement so. 
All examples are either showing arrays or listview.

Is there a better way so that the textview "editTextTotal" to get the itemTotal?

if it helps,
the .xml file for the activity_display_product.xml is as follows. 
All except the editTextTotal are correctly assigned.

**activity_display_product.xml**

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextQuantity"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text|number" />
```

Comment: Why are you not inserting total value at insert query?

Comment: wont inserting total value at the InsertProduct() allow user to add the total value. the application needs to calculate the total value.

i also tried that initially but it caused the application to crash

Comment: Actually problem is that you are inserting String value in **insert()** method instead of double value which is type of column in create table. It is good things to use same type in create,insert,select,update etc. all queries. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is hear

```
cost text, quantity text, total text
```

you have added as text, first parse into this string to double then calculate your 
desire calculations.

Comment: doesnt the method getItemTotal() wraps the text into double?